# How to use startup feh options in midnight commander in debian jessie?

Tags: image, viewer, mc

When I press enter on an image file in `mc`, the image is opend by `feh` but is displayed full-sized. That's bad. It should fit the image to screen size by default. Simple as a pie, `feh` has `--auto-zoom` option to do this. But there is no `feh` command in  `mc.ext` config file. It's got

```
include/image
        Open=/usr/lib/mc/ext.d/image.sh open ALL_FORMATS
        View=%view{ascii} /usr/lib/mc/ext.d/image.sh view ALL_FORMATS
```

`image.sh` in turn is using `xdg-open` to open and view files, BUT `man xdg-open` does not say how to configure `xdg-open` so that the `feh` it is using becomes `feh --auto-zoom`. So, is it possible to add `--auto-zoom` option to `feh` used by `midnight commander` in Debian Jessie at all and how?

Comment: This should help https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2016/10/msg00286.html

Comment: That's how feh is configured on my box. The problem is it does not accept `--auto-zoom` command line option when this option is included in any of the xdg configuration files I could find.